# Stata Nested foreach loop substring comparison

Tags: loops, foreach, nested, substring, stata

I have just started learning Stata and I'm having a hard time. 
My problem is this: I have two different variables, `ATC` and `A`, where `A` is potentially a substring of `ATC`.
Now I want to mark all the observations in which `A` is a substring of `ATC` with `OK = 1`.

I tried this using a simple nested loop:

```
foreach x in ATC {
foreach j in A {
        replace OK = 1 if strpos(`x',`j')!=0
    }
}
```

However, whenever I run this loop no changes are being made even though there should be plenty. 
I feel like I should probably give an index specifying which `OK` is being changed (the one belonging to the `ATC`/x), but I have no idea how to do this. This is probably really simple but I've been struggling with it for some time.

---

I should have clarified: my `A` list is separate from the main list (simply appended to it) and only contains unique keys which I use to identify the `ATC`s which I want. So I have ~120 `A`-keys and a couple million `ATC` keys. What I wanted to do was iterate over every `ATC` key for every single `A`-key and mark those `ATC`-keys with `A` that qualify.

That means I don't have complete tuples of (`ATC`,`A`,`OK`) but instead separate lists of different sizes.
For example: I have

```
ATC    OK  A 
ABCD   0   .
EFGH   0   .
...   ...  ...
.     .    AB
.     .    ET
```

and want the result that `"ABCD"` having `OK` is marked as `1` while `"EFGH"` remains at `0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can separate your question into two parts. Your title implies a problem with loops, but your loops are just equivalent to

```
  replace OK = 1 if strpos(ATC, A)!=0
```

so the use of looping appears irrelevant. That leaves the substring comparison.

Let's supply an example:

```
. set obs 3 
obs was 0, now 3

. gen OK = 0 

. gen A = cond(_n == 1, "42", "something else")  

. gen ATC = "answer is 42"

. replace OK = 1 if strpos(ATC, A) != 0 
(1 real change made)

. list 

     +------------------------------------+
    | OK                A            ATC |
    |------------------------------------|
 1. |  1               42   answer is 42 |
 2. |  0   something else   answer is 42 |
 3. |  0   something else   answer is 42 |
    +------------------------------------+
```

So it works fine; and you really need to give a reproducible example if you think you have something different.

As for specifying where the variable should be changed: your code does precisely that, as again the example above shows.

---

The update makes the problem clear. Stata will only look in the same observation for a matching substring when you specify the syntax you gave. A variable in Stata is a field in a dataset. To cycle over a set of values, something like this should suffice

```
 gen byte OK = 0 
 levelsof A, local(Avals) 

 quietly foreach A of local Avals { 
     replace OK = 1 if strpos(ATC, `"`A'"') > 0 
 }
```

Notes:

1. Specifying `byte` cuts down storage.
2. You may need an `if` or `in` restriction on `levelsof`.
3. `quietly` cuts out messages about changed values. When debugging, it is often better left out.
4. `> 0` could be omitted as a positive result from `strpos()` is automatically treated as true in logical comparisons. See [this FAQ](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/true-and-false/index.html).

Comment: I edited my original post. I probably should have given an example from the beginning, thank you for your help either way. I apologize for my poor formatting etc. as I dont use this site very much.