# How do I "fill down" a dataset in Stata, but for only a certain number of rows?

Tags: stata, missing-data

I have a dataset with observations at specific timepoints, but those timepoints (and the length of time between them) vary by group.  I'm trying to "fill down" the data so that existing observations are carried down into missing cells.  But I only want to do this for a certain number of rows after the original observation.  So for example, I could have a dataset that looks like this:

[image]

For group A, I'd want to fill in the value for 2002 with 2001's value, 2004 with 2003, etc.  I wouldn't want to fill in 2000 at all, since I don't have the preceding value.  And I ALSO wouldn't want to fill in the 2011 value, because the "cyclelength" variable tells me that group A's observations are supposed to take place every two years, so I don't want to carry data forward past that.  2011 is just a genuinely missing value.

Similarly, in group B, I'd want to carry 2000's value forward into years 2001, 2002, and 2003 (because the "cyclelength" here is 4 years).  I'd want to carry 2004's value into 2005, 2006, and 2007, but not beyond that--the later years should stay missing.

I've tried setting this up with the "carryforward" command, but haven't figured out how to have it stop filling down after a specified number of years that varies by group.  Is there a way to do this, either with carryforward or otherwise?

Comment: This is clear and specific, but for future questions please note (1) data posted as image are more difficult to copy and paste for experiment (2) many members here prefer to see attempts at code.

Comment: Thank you for both these points, and for the answer.  I did a quick search to see if there was some accepted way of posting tabular data on SE and didn't find much-- is there a commonly-used way to embed data with multiple columns such that they maintain their formatting and can be copy-pasted?

Comment: Copying and pasting from a listing can be enough. http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting gives detail, but indenting 4 spaces is the first trick to learn that gets you a long way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27337523/stata-nested-foreach-loop-substring-comparison/27337707#27337707 illustrates a useful technique, code that creates data sufficient to show the key point.

Comment: Great, will do that in future.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a variation on a problem documented since 2000 as an FAQ: see [here](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/replacing-missing-values/)

The variation lies in limiting how far non-missing values are copied. But it falls easily to the same idea.

The last known value was recorded in certain years which we can copy down the dataset:

```
  gen when_last_known = year if !missing(value) 
  bysort group (year) : replace when_last_known = when_last_known[_n-1] if missing(when_last_known)
```

Now the replacement wanted is

```
  by group : replace value = value[_n-1] if missing(value) & (year - when_last_known) < cyclelength
```

That statement presupposes the `sort` order of the previous statement.

On Statalist ([see here](http://www.statalist.org)) you'd be expected to document that `carryforward` is a user-written command to be installed from SSC. That's a good convention here too.

In practice, it's good data management to keep the original data exactly as they arrive and do this on a clone of the variable. Sooner or later someone will ask to see the original values, and then you could be seriously embarrassed.